# JS: Converting dictionary to a list of dictionaries

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, dictionary

I have a dictionary and I want to map it so that it becomes a list of dictionaries. How would I do that in js?

```
var dict = {
"key1" : 100,
"key2" : 200,
"key3" : 300
}
```

```
var data = [
{"key1" : 100},
{"key2" : 200},
{"key3" : 300}
]
```

Comment: Why would you do that? It's harder to work with the resulting data structure. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries()` to convert the object to an array of key-value pairs. You can then `.map()` this array to an array of objects.

```js
var dict = {
  "key1" : 100,
  "key2" : 200,
  "key3" : 300
}

var data = Object.entries(dict).map(([key, value]) => ({[key]: value}))

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use `Object.entries` and `map` to make `key` `value` objects

```js
var dict = {
  "key1" : 100,
  "key2" : 200,
  "key3" : 300
  }

  const re=Object.entries(dict).map(o=>({[o[0]]:o[1]}))
  console.log(re)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys()` and `Array.map()` to get the result:

```js
var dict = {
"key1" : 100,
"key2" : 200,
"key3" : 300
}

let result = Object.keys(dict).map(k => ({[k]: dict[k]}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply declare a variable to store list and loop through dict. On each iteration make a dict from key value and push in list.

```js
var dict = {
  "key1": 100,
  "key2": 200,
  "key3": 300
}
var data = [];
for (key in dict) {
  var subDict = {}
  subDict[key] = dict[key]
  data.push(subDict)
}
console.log(data)
```