# How to convert Map<string,boolean> to {key: string; value: boolean;}[]?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, dictionary, react-tsx

I'm using React with TypeScript support and on the user creation page, I have implemented the dynamic creation of permissions, following [this peace of code](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/add-or-remove-input-fields-dynamically-with-reactjs-mt3vem?file=%2Fsrc%2FInputs.js).
The permissions used on the page are set by the following hook:

```
const [permissions, setPermissions] = useState<{ perm: string; isTrue: boolean; }[]>([]);
```

The interface `IUser`, however, has permissions specified as follows:

```
export interface IUser {
    permissions: Map<string, boolean>
}
```

How can I convert `Map<string, boolean>` type to `{ perm: string; isTrue: boolean; }[]`?

I've tried using `Map.prototype.forEach()` and `Map.prototype.entries()`, but couldn't figure out how to bring their results to the right type.

I also know that the reverse conversion can be done using the [following trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62866828/22873508), but not sure if it can be used the other way around.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQFUBnNOAbwCg4a4w0BbBY4hCJYgLjgFlMwAPMRhRkAcwA0cAEYQIAG2CYkAPgDclAL6VKAE2DZ5mKHmzthdRs1bm+YbnaEjxU2QqWqNlMx3j0oTCxsHACCUFCYAJ5wALxwYRGRAHToUBAMABT+gTYcdlIZANrZUswAKlAArsAAugCUsSpwGeSWAaXEFdVwmnV1GgD0A7RwAHoA-JRAA) meet your needs? If so, I'll be happy to write up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from?retiredLocale=de) with a custom map callback function parameter that destructures each Map item into its key (=`perm`) and value (=`isTrue`) and creates a new object from that.

```
export interface IUser {
  permissions: Map<string, boolean>;
}

declare const permissionsMap: Map<string, boolean>;

const permissionsArray = Array.from(permissionsMap, ([perm, isTrue]) => ({
  perm,
  isTrue,
}));
// const permissionsArray: { perm: string; isTrue: boolean; }[]
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQFUBnNOAbwCg44w0BbBY4hCJYgLjgFlMwAeYjCjIA5gBo4AIwgQANsExIAfAG5KAX0qUAJsGxzMUPNjZDaDJizO8wXW4OFjJM+YpXrKp9vDpRGzKzsAIJQUJgAnnAAvHCh4REAdOhQEPQAFH4B1uy2kukA2lmSTAAqUACuwAC6AJQxynDpVDTF1IjE5VXimrW16gD0A3De5llWQcTxkVzkFv5cQiJIoqodXcBcrgpKaxoF1ZRAA)